# Dynamic rating and description in smart app banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my application i have created smart app banner for mobile app(Android/IOS).If I click the open button according to my mobile device i am target to (Android app - google play) or (IOS app - Apple store) of my app. But In banner i am not getting dynamic description and rating from (App store/google play). so please any one help me to get description and rating dynamically from (App store/google play).

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for are APIs.

Regarding App Store you may take a look to the [iTunes Search API](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api) (see the lookup section) which will give you a nice JSON object representing the app. I'd suggest to fiddle with it to understand better how it works.

In regard to Play Store there are no official APIs, while some unofficial versions are available. Take a look at this [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-API-for-the-Google-Play-Store) for further informations.