# How can I add rating on smart banner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, banner

I get smart banner from here : https://github.com/kudago/smart-app-banner

The code like this :

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Smartbanner test</title>
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=502838820">
<meta name="google-play-app" content="app-id=ru.hh.android">
<meta name="msApplication-ID" content="microsoft.build.App"/>
<meta name="msApplication-PackageFamilyName" content="microsoft.build_8wekyb3d8bbwe"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dist/smart-app-banner.css">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">
<link rel="android-touch-icon" href="icon.png" />
<link rel="windows-touch-icon" href="icon.png" />
<style type="text/css">
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/smart-app-banner.js"></script>

<script>
    banner = undefined;
    function run(force) {
        var n = document.querySelector('.smartbanner');
        if (n) {
            n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
        }
        new SmartBanner({
                daysHidden: 15, // days to hide banner after close button is clicked (defaults to 15)
                daysReminder: 90, // days to hide banner after "VIEW" button is clicked (defaults to 90)
                appStoreLanguage: 'us', // language code for the App Store (defaults to user's browser language)
                title: 'KudaGo',
                author: 'KudaGo Inc',
                button: 'OPEN',
                force: force
        });
    };
</script>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="#" onclick="run('android')">android</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="run('ios')">ios</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="run('windows')">windows</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

The result like this :

[image]

I want to add rating like this :

[image]

I read on the documentation, but I don't find it

How can I add rating on the smart banner?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545974/dynamic-rating-and-description-in-smart-app-banner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545974/dynamic-rating-and-description-in-smart-app-banner)

Comment: @Sfili_81 I find this : https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000764837-Smart-banners#introduction. Seems it's more simple

Comment: @Sfili_81  Are there more specific references? I am having trouble implementing it